# ASP.NET MVC bool value returned from the view is 1 or 0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, boolean, model-binding, checkboxfor

I am using ASP.NET MVC, and I have some problems using a CheckBoxFor. Here is my problem:

I have the following code in the view:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.stade, new { @id = "stade" })
```

`model.stade` is of type bool. In my controller, I have:

```
//Editar
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult InvoiceType(int Id, string Name, string Code, string Stade)
{
    clsInvoiceTypea Model = new clsInvoiceType();
    Model.Id = Id;
    Model.Name = Name;
    Model.Code = Code;
    Model.Stade = stade== "1" ? true : false;
    return PartialView(Model);
}
```

I get an error, because when `Model.Stade` is submitted to the view the value is 1 or 0, and I get an error saying "Can not recognize the string as a valid Boolean", but if Model.stade is boolean why the model is submitted to the view like 0 or 1? How I can I resolve this?

Comment: Rather than trying to bind to individual properties, bind the model instead `public ActionResult InvoiceType(clsInvoiceTypea model)`.

Comment: This code won't compile (hint: `Stade` != `stade`)

Comment: sorry, that was because I translated the code to english, I speak spanish

Comment: Stephen, the problem is because the model has a bool value Model.Stade and the action public ActionResult InvoiceType() get 1 or 0 for Model.Stade and this value is boolean then a get a error

Answer (score 2):

Here  goes my solution -

Let your Model be -

```
public class clsInvoiceTypea
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public bool stade { get; set; }
    }
```

Let your HttpGet Action be -

```
public ActionResult GetInvoice()
{
    clsInvoiceTypea type = new clsInvoiceTypea();
    return View(type);
}
```

And the corresponding view -

```
@model YourValidNameSpace.clsInvoiceTypea

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GetInvoice";
}

<h2>GetInvoice</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitData","Home",FormMethod.Post)) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>clsInvoiceTypea</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Code)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Code)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Code)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.stade)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.stade)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.stade)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Let the following be your HttpPost Action -

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SubmitData(clsInvoiceTypea model)
{
    return View();
}
```

When you run the code, you will get following view -

[image]

When you select the checkbox and hit the create button, if you put a breakpoint on POST method and check the value, you will get true.

[image]

Comment: thanks, but the problem is that when I send the model.stade value from the view to the controler this recieved 1 or 0 and when a send the model from the controller to the view is the same, the value is 1 or 0 and this get a error because model.state is the bool type and not accept numbers

Comment: I dont understand why a bool value is changed for a number?

Comment: public class clsInvoiceType
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "El nombre es obligatorio")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "El código es obligatorio")]
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public bool Stade { get; set; }}

Comment: sorry but I dont know how to put a new line in this foro

Comment: The problem is very strange, when I send the model from the controller to the view @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.stade, new { @id = "stade" }) receive to 1 or 0 and this get a error, and when I send the model from the view to the action public ActionResult InvoiceType(clsInvoiceType model) the atribute Stade receive a 1 or 0 and get a error because is not posible to convert a number into boolean value, What Can I do?